# Add an item click listener directly to dynamically populated context menu in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I have a context menu in WPF which will be driven by a `List<String>` to display a dynamically generated set of menu items.

The list is assigned to the `ItemsSource` property of the context menu, and correctly displays the content of the menu.

It I create a `MenuItem` in code behind, I can assign a click listener to the item, and then add that item to the `Items` list of the menu which correctly populates the list, and allows each item to call the click listener.

I have implemented this approach as shown below.

```
 private ContextMenu _elementContextMenu;

    public ContextMenu ElementContextMenu {
        get {
            if (_elementContextMenu == null) {
                _elementContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                //root menu item
                _elementMenuRootItem = new MenuItem();
                _elementMenuRootItem.Click += _elementMenuRootItem_Click;
                _elementMenuRootItem.ItemsSource = ElementMenuContent;

                _elementContextMenu.Items.Add(_elementMenuRootItem);
            }
            return _elementContextMenu;
        }
        set { _elementContextMenu = value; }
    }
```

Using that approach, the click listener passes the clicked menu item as the source of the event, and I can cast it to a `MenuItem` as shown below:

```
  void _elementMenuRootItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MenuItem selectedMenuItem = (MenuItem)e.OriginalSource;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is a list of items which show up as the root of the list.

If I bind the list of menu items (name `ElementMenuContent` in this implementation) to the `ItemsSource` property of the context menu, the menu is populated as I would like it to be, however there is no `Click` event in the `ContextMenu`.

The desired implementation is shown below:

```
    public ContextMenu ElementContextMenu {
        get {
            if (_elementContextMenu == null) {
                _elementContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                _elementContextMenu.ItemsSource = ElementMenuContent;

                //Add a click listener directly to the ContextMenu object which allows
                //the source menu item which was clicked to be referenced in the same way 
                //as with a MenuItem click listener
            }
            return _elementContextMenu;
        }
        set { _elementContextMenu = value; }
    }
```

The component this is being implemented in extends the WPF `Canvas`, and is a .cs file only, so this must be implemented entirely in code. I cannot use XAML in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this part of your question:

> What I want to achieve is a list of items which show up as the root of the list.

As you said, there is no **Click** event available on the ContextMenu itself. The simplest solution would be to instead subscribe to **PreviewMouseUp** which will capture all mouse click activity and then you can use the MouseButtonEventArgs to access what you need.

**PreviewMouseUp**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup?view=netframework-4.7.2

If this doesn't help, you can always look into creating a custom routed event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event

Comment: This was how I first tried to make this work, and it did correctly act on the mouse click, however it didn't allow me to easily get the content of the menu item. The solution I went with in the end was to attach a handler in code behind. This is straightforward in XAML, but not so intuitive with just c# code.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stuck on this same issue, the solution is to set the `ItemsSource` property of the menu itself (in this case, the `ElementMenuContent` object is a `List<String>`, and add an event handler to the `ContextMenu` which operates on the `ClickEvent` of any `MenuItem` component as follows:

```
    _elementContextMenu.ItemsSource = ElementMenuContent;

    _elementContextMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ElementContextMenuItemClick));
```

The handler method is defined as normal.

```
    public void ElementContextMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MenuItem selectedMenuItem = (MenuItem)e.OriginalSource;
        String command = selectedMenuItem.Header.ToString();
        SwimLaneController.Instance.ProcessContextMenuCommand(this, command);
    }
```